# How to detect if a field is primary key or not

Tags: android, sqlite

My question is that it is possible to know a field is primary key of table by looking cursor. Or how can we learn which field is primary key?

I want write a class like that. So I must learn it programatically

```
public class BO {

private HashMap<String, Object> data;
private String primaryKey="";


public BO() {
    data=new HashMap<String, Object>();
}

public String getUpdateQuery() {
    return null;
}

public String getInsertQusery() {
    return null;
}

public String getPrimaryKey() {
    return primaryKey;
}

public void setPrimaryKey(String primaryKey) {
    this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
}

public int getLogicalReference() {
    return logicalReference;
}

public void loadDataFromCursor(Cursor cur){
    String[] fields=cur.getColumnNames();
    for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
        switch (cur.getType(i)) {
        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
            data.put(fields[i], cur.getInt(i));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void setLogicalReference(int logicalReference) {
    this.logicalReference = logicalReference;
}
```

}

Comment: Since it is your table, you should know. I don't really see in what situation you'd need this.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info

Comment: I add some code. I must leart it programaticaly to perform this action

Comment: Primary keys are properties of tables, not of queries/cursors. Your question does not make sense. What do you need this information for?

Comment: I want to learn primary key column name

Comment: i don't understand at which point you need this. Anyway, BaseColumns._ID is usually a good primary key, and most sqlite table have it (it is the default primary key if no other is specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like CL. said in his comment, I believe a Cursor does not hold this information. Whether a column holds a primary key is related to the table structure, which is different from the content of the table. A Cursor is used to access data and not give information about the table's structure.

Besides, the Cursor interface in Android is not necessarily related to a SQLiteDatabase, so you should not be able to get this kind of information from it.

However, I can't think of any good usage case where this should be really useful. Maybe some kind of far-fetched genericity of the code; in any case, there is a good chance you should rethink your design (or explain it if you really think it's correct; in that case, I'm curious !)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Python and Mysql.

```
pkey = cursor.execute("SHOW KEYS FROM " + tablename + " WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'")
```

And the Use Case :

```
Query =  "INSERT INTO table " + str(tuple(table[0].keys()))
Query += "\nVALUES\n"
Query += str(tuple(table[0].values()))
Query += "\nON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE\n"
for key in table[0].keys():
   if not key in pkey:
       Query += key + " = VALUES(" + key + "),\n"
Query = Query.rstrip(",")
cursor.execute(Query)
```

The resulting string would Insert or Update the table.  If you try to push the Primary Key to the table you throw an error of Duplicate Primary.  My program is parsing a directory of JSON files and importing them into database as part of an API retrieval process.  I am pulling data from 3 different API's and would like to keep the code generic so that I can re-use it.

I am less familiar with SQLLite, however you could implement something that would do this for you, by naming your primary key with something that indicated it was a primary key : pk_id for example and then just parsing the name of the field to find if it contains pk.